# Access Azure Blob storage of a user using oauth2 token obtained

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure blob storage what I need is to get the access token when a user signs into his account, and by using this access token to perform list/upload/download the files in user blob storage.(Similar to what we can do in Dropbox/Google drive).
Using the given request user authentication I am getting the code,

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2Fuser_impersonation&state=12345
```

And the code is used to get the token using the below request

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id=client_id&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2Fuser_impersonation&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=client_secret
```

But when I call get request to list using `https://account_name.blob.core.windows.net/container_name?restype=container&comp=list` I am getting `server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature`. How to access the files in the blob storage using the token obtained? Can we do this using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access Azure blob storage with Azure AD, please refer to the following steps:

1. Register Azure AD application
2. Configure Azure APplication

   a.  Configure permissions
      [image]
      [image]
3. Configure RABC role for the user

```
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --assignee <email> \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

4. Get token
   a. get code

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
   client_id=<>
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
   &state=12345
   ```

   b. get token

   ```
   Post     https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/token
   client_id=<>
   &scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
   &code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &client_secret=<>
   ```
5. Call Azure blob rest api

```
Get https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
Headers : 
            Authorization: Bearer <>
            x-ms-version: 2019-02-02
```

[image]

Comment: I want to access a users account who gives permission to use his azure storage account to upload/delete/download files using the token obtained when he gives the permission. RBAC can be set, but I cannot ask the users to set that role permission in his account for me.

Comment: @subin_john_ According to the situation, you may have two choices. One is that you can ask the user to create a service principal for you and set ```Storage Blob Data Contributor``` role for the sp. Then you can use the sp access the storage. The other one is that you can ask the user to create a sas token for you then you can access the storage with the sas token.

Comment: Ok will try that way, Thank you

Comment: @subin_john_  Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concern, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It may help more people who have similar issues.