# Only allow authorized users to access blob urls in an azure storage container

Tags: azure-blob-storage

If I configure the access level of a blob to private, the blob url is inaccessible even for those whose AD accounts have been added to the storage account.

How can I allow the blob url to be accessed only by a particular group of users?
According to another stackoverflow link it seems I have to offer access key equivalent information to allow a private blob to be accessed. In such a case, anyone who owns the access key can access the blob as if the access level were public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your need, I suggest you can use Shared access signatures or Azure Active Directory authorization to access your blob. And I do not suggest you share your access key with other people. Because it is not safe. Once someone has the [access key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#protect-your-access-keys), he can directly manage the storage account. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

---

## Update

If you want to access privet blob with Azure AD auth, please refer to the following steps
1. Register Azure AD application

2. Configure Azure APplication

   a.  Configure permissions
      [image]
      [image]
3. Configure RABC role for the user

```
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --assignee <email> \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

4. Get token
   a. get code

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
   client_id=<>
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
   &state=12345
   ```

   b. get token

   ```
   Post     https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/token
   client_id=<>
   &scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
   &code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &client_secret=<>
   ```
5. Call Azure blob rest api

```
Get https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
Headers : 
            Authorization: Bearer <>
            x-ms-version: 2019-02-02
```

[image]

Besides, you also can use sas token to access Azure Blob. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.
For example

```
$account="blobstorage0516"
$key=""
$container="test"
$blob="test.json"
$context= New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account -StorageAccountKey $key
 Write-host "The blob access level :"(Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Name test -Context $context).PublicAccess  -ForegroundColor red


$sas=New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container $container -Blob $blob -Permission r -Context $context
$url="https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${container}/${blob}${sas}"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -OutFile e:\test.json
Write-host "download successfully"
```

[image]

Comment: The Azure storage account is AD authenticated. If I upload a blob to a container, even AD authenticated users cannot access the blob url if it is private. I would like authenticated users to be able to access the url from an email.

Comment: @Learner If you want to use AD authenticated to access blob, you need to assign an Azure RABC role(such as Storage Blob Data Contributor) to the user. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory

Comment: My AD role (Storage Blob Data Contributor) has been assigned to the storage account. However, I cannot access a private blob that is located in the container of the storage account. What else configuration is required? Thanks.

Comment: @Learner Could you please tell me your error and your steps?

Comment: @Learner You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406391/access-azure-blob-storage-of-a-user-using-oauth2-token-obtained/59419348?noredirect=1#comment105027163_59419348 to know how to access Azure blob storge with Azure AD auth

Comment: Using the above configuration, there is no way for authorized users to download the private blob (say a pdf file) by clicking a URL address, right?

Comment: @Learner After you finish Azure AD auth, you will get Azure AD access token. Then you can download the blob with the access token. For more details, please refer to my update

Comment: Many thanks I will try your AD solution later. Just a quick question, do you think it is possible to allow only the authorized users to download the private blob just by just clicking the url in a notification email with all the other necessities implemented on the back end?

Comment: @Learner As far as I knew, we may do that. We click the url, open a window and do Azure AD auth then download the blob.

Comment: Thanks and I will select your answer next week.

Comment: Could you help me further? How does the link that the user clicks first look like? It is not the blob URL that can be found at Azure portal, right? " https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob" should be the actual URL.

Comment: Could you help me further? How does the link that the user clicks first look like? Could it be some particular URL +  the actual blob URL(query string format).  " https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob" should be the actual URL.

Comment: @Lenrner Since it is a new issue, I suggest you raise a new question in StackOverflow then you can call me, I will help you.